# How do I make `w` command show the full command?

Tags: bash

When I run a long command `w` just shows part of it by default.

[image]

How do I make it show the full command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is designed to produce a columnar layout, and for that reason truncates all output that exceeds the character width of the current display. Otherwise, it would be wrapped and render the output less structured. In a larger terminal window, e.g. after you maximized the terminal, more output will be shown when running the command again.

A trick to see all output wrapped within a smaller window, but loosing some of the column formatting, would be to pipe the output to cat:

```
w | cat
```

Comment: As an alternative, piping to `tee` or `more` would also generate similar results.